# Get drush and composer to work in the Visual Studio Code terminal

Tags: command-line, visual-studio-code, windows-10, drupal-8, drush

I cannot use the terminal with Drush in Visual Studio Code. Every time I ran drush or composer I get the following error:

**drush : The term 'drush' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ drush
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (drush:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException**

I have Windows 10, I am working on Drupal 8 locally. I have drush and composer installed. They are working fine using my local windows command line but not on the  Visual Studio Code terminal. The reason why I wanted to use the VSC terminal because is more convenient.

Comment: Have you tried following this guide https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/development-tools/configuring-visual-studio-code

Comment: thx @pwaterz. I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by installing a plugin called "Composer" by Ioannis Kappas and edit your settings.json to recognize the plugin. You can get all the info you need about the plugin at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ikappas.composer